# Change the CRC32 polynomial in JAVA

Tags: java, crc32

I need to use a different polynomial for JAVA's CRC32 implementation. I need to use CRC32Q, whose polynomial is 0x814141AB.

Is there any way to change the used polynomial, maybe extending the java.util.zip.CRC32 class?

Comment: You'll have to implement it yourself. Make sure you use a table-driven version, not the version that shifts bits of the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CRC calculation is a native method (see [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/zip/CRC32.java)) and there does not appear to be any way of plugging in a different implementation.  You likely will have to write your own class implementing the `Checksum` interface.  It will probably be a lot slower.

Comment: So I can implement Checksum, but I can't extend CRC32? Does that sound like a lot of trouble, or do I just have a lazy day?

Comment: CRC32 isn't hard to implement but if you want native performance it's more work :-(